# Are there issues having this feature workflow with Git?

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

I'm currently in the middle of migrating Subversions repositories over to Git. The issue I have is managing the large number of changes that are ongoing for a particular project. Some changes can be abandoned and it's leaving Subversion branches broken.

Given Git's flexibility in it's branching, I am proposing the following workflow:

### Core layout:

- **master** branch - Restricted to pull requests only. Senior developers to sign off.
- **develop** branch - Available to all developers. Bleeding edge features merged into here. May not always be working
- **uat** branch - Available to all developers. Tested features that are ready for the client to test
- **staging** branch - Available to all developers. To be populated with production-ready, signed off features only
- **feature/*** - For all work to be completed after project launch. A feature could be some text changes or a significant development of site features

### Typical working scenario:

- Client has requested a new feature on the website
- Developer creates a new feature branch from master and codes the new feature. Feature is regularly merged into develop
- Once the feature is ready for testing, the feature is merged into the uat branch
- Any further adjustments are made in the feature and merged into the uat branch
- Once client is happy with new feature, it is merged into staging, which is a replica of master
- On completion of merge to staging, a pull request is generated to discuss code merging from staging into master ready for deployment to production servers
- Further changes requested in the pull request are made into the feature and merged into staging
- On completion of pull request, master is merged into develop and uat
- Feature is to be removed after a period of time

With the above I'm trying to eliminate

- Issues with cleaning abandoned features. Worst case with the above setup, the develop branch can be dropped, cloned from uat or master and have ongoing features merged back into it.
- Cherry picking completed features in develop to put into uat or master, which is what is currently happening in Subversion
- Unauthorised tampering of production code. With the above, developers can prove that code works with the staging environment and request to have code reviewed before merged into master. Our Subversion solution allows developers to merge into 'trunk' but they cannot deploy, which can get messy with when bad code is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's a valid workflow and I don't know of nothing to be improved (using a similar one here). If you want formal validation (I guess you already looked at these) it's pretty much described in the Feature-Branch Workflow on this [page](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch). The graduation (staging->uat->master) workflow is also described [in the manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html).

Given gits flexibility you are also not stuck to this workflow forever so if you find that something not works out you can alway tweak it (and due to the distributed nature anybody can use his own micro-workflow anyway without screwing things up).

So yes valid workflow, should eliminate the things you want to eliminate and should accomodate the workflow you described.

Details still always depend on the situation but like I said it is a great start to iterate from if need arises.

Comment: Thanks! As you mentioned, the good thing about Git is that we can drop this model and move onto something else if it doesn't work. I can't see any major plot holes but I'm sure if there are any we'll find them soon! Our client size requires there to be a untouched UAT environment and the potential need to see changes in develop at the same time, so that is where the model works also I guess

Comment: And there you run into one of the fe problems of git: you will have to enforce this by convention and or external tools (whips if you prefer hardware or just write restrictions on the central repository/ies) because git doesn't support write protection natively

Comment: Yup. We're giving Bitbucket a go as a result of that. Write access on all branches except master, where admins/senior devs can manage pull requests.